# Sorting a list in response mapping template in AWS AppSync

Tags: aws-appsync, vtl

I’m having some trouble with sorting within a response mapping template in AppSync. I’ve tried something like below, but this just returns the list un-sorted.

```
$util.toJson($util.list.sortList($results, false, "position"))
```

However if I harcode the list like this (a bit simplified for brevity), it works

```
$util.toJson($util.list.sortList([{"position":1},{"position":5}, {"position":3}], false, "position"))
```

What am I missing?

Response mapping template

```
#set($results = [])
    #foreach($res in $ctx.result.items)
        #set($item = {})
        $util.qr($item.put("imageId", $res.SK))
        $util.qr($item.put("url", $res.URL))
        $util.qr($item.put("position", $res.Position))
        $util.qr($results.add($item))
    #end

$util.toJson($results)
```

Result

```
{
  "data": {
    "myQuery": {
      "images": [
        {
          "imageId": "someid1",
          "url": "https...",
          "position": 3
        },
        {
          "imageId": "someid2",
          "url": "https...",
          "position": 1
        },
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$results` supposed to refer to? `$util.toJson($util.list.sortList($ctx.result.data.myQuery.images, false, "position"))` works as expected for me.

Comment: `$results` is the response for the query with the object properties being changed to be more descriptive for the API consumer.